# ContentPresenter not lay-outing properly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm working on a Universal App (XAML and C# combination) and I have created a custom control that should act like a sort of card view. Flipping the card brings up other content. To do this, I'm using two ContentPresenters and some animations (visual states) to rotate the ContentPresenters when needed so that at all times only one is visible.

The animations work fine, however, I'm having a lay-out issue, where a TextBlock inside the ContentPresenter's DataTemplate is not stretched across the entire width of the control. Trying to reproduce this behaviour by creating a separate ContentPresenter and adding the exact same content works fine. It must be some error in my Style for the control, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

You can see the Style I have used below (to clarify, I'm leaving out the visual states because I don't think that's the point.)

```
<Style TargetType="controls:FlipCard">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:FlipCard">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid x:Name="FrontContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection RotationX="0" RotationY="0" />
                        </Grid.Projection>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Front" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding Front}" FontWeight="Light" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="BackContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection RotationX="0" RotationY="0" />
                        </Grid.Projection>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Back" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding Back}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <!-- Rotate around X-axis -->
                            <VisualState x:Name="FlipForwardShowBack">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="FrontContainer">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="90"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="90"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackContainer">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-90"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-90"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.FontFamily)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <FontFamily>Global User Interface</FontFamily>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FlipForwardShowFront">
                                ...
                            </VisualState>

                            ...
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If anyone can help me out, I would very much appreciate it! Thanks! :)
PS: If you want to see the problem in action, you can download a sample project here: http://1drv.ms/1BdRPQ0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno the logic behind it but I don't see the reason to override `MeasureOverride`.

Just comment out the whole `protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. The logic behind overriding it was because only one side is visible and the other side might be larger than the current side. So the control should "reserve" enough space. However, with it commented out, it still works fine! Thank you.
Unfortunately, it seems like I can't upvote you yet :(

Comment: No worries. Nice control you have created there! :)

Comment: Planning to blog about it once it's completely finished up ;)